# Python Bloomberg tia.bbg get mora than 2500 rows returned

Tags: python, bloomberg

Trying to get all the index members from Bloomberg using Python, but it is only returning 2.5k securities.

```
from tia.bbg import LocalTerminal

resp = LocalTerminal.get_reference_data('LUACTRUU Index','INDX_MEMBERS')
members = resp.as_frame().iloc[0,0]
```

Anyone can figure it out why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INDX_MEMBERS2` and `INDX_MEMBERS3` to get the constituents 2,501 to 5,000 and 5,001 to 7,500 respectively.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much. Secondly, how the heck did this work and why?

Comment: I don't know! You can ask Bloomberg why they didn't put the whole thing on a single field but I doubt you'll get an answer...

Comment: You cannot ask BBG, because that is not a BBG API but some wrapper written by someone outside of BBG.  It is also untouched since 2015 and only works for Python 2.7.  In general, BBG has data limits, and if you pull a very large index (or all SPX options or something similar), and it would give you everything, you will blow the limit with a single request.

Comment: The wrapped is built on the Bloomberg API and that's where the limitation comes from. You could write the same formula in Excel with the same result.